# php - How do I sort a numeric data string into an array based on decimal values?

Tags: php

I have a set of data which is a breakdown of call charges for international phone number prefixes. I need to parse the data so that I know the per minute cost of calling any number. The format is the cost followed by the prefixes. It is one big mess. the data looks like this: `cost,prefix,prefix,prefix,cost,prefix,prefix,prefix,prefix`.

The number of prefixes varies, but the cost is always 0.something (eg. `0.345`)

Example:

`0.43,123,124,125,0.64,567,568,569`

I need to reformat the data so I can programatically grab the cost of calling any prefix, so I know that calling prefix 123 costs 0.43 dollars, and calling 567 costs 0.64 dollars etc. For example, maybe I could lookup the desired prefix and find the cost that precedes it.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Does the data set imply that if a prefix is not preceded by a cost that it does not have a cost defined? For example the prefixes 124 and 125 do not have an associated cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reformat the data by using [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) on the string, and iterating over it to find the costs, like so:

```
$string = '0.43,123,124,125,0.64,567,568,569';
$costs = array(); $current_price = null;
foreach( explode( ',', $string) as $value) {
    if( $value < 1) {
        $current_price = $value;
    } else {
        $costs[ $value ] = $current_price;
    }
}
```

Now, you have a look-up table with the key being the prefix, and you can look-up the costs by accessing the index for your prefix, like so:

```
echo "It costs " . $costs[ 125 ] . " to call prefix 125";
```

In fact, your `$costs` array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [123] => 0.43
    [124] => 0.43
    [125] => 0.43
    [567] => 0.64
    [568] => 0.64
    [569] => 0.64
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code you can use:

```
    <?php

$string = "0.43,123,124,125,0.64,567,568,569";

$arr = explode (',',$string);

$callrates =[];
$rate;
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    if(strstr($value,'.')){
        $rate = $value;
    }else{
        $callrates[$value]  = $rate;
    }
}
```

Test `print_r($callrates);` produces

```
Array
(
    [123] => 0.43
    [124] => 0.43
    [125] => 0.43
    [567] => 0.64
    [568] => 0.64
    [569] => 0.64
)
```

But then accepted answer already does the same